# Hive regexp_extract returning NULL

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, regex-group

Relatively new to the world of regular expressions so please bear with me.
I am trying to use regexp_extract to pull out a certain subset of data within the string but it is returning me NULL for the regular expression I am currently trying to use.

The requirement is as follows :-

String --> test=**1233**]3212] --> Extract 1233

String --> test=**123355** --> 123355

The idea is to extract all data after test= upto either the first ] or the end of string.

The regular expression I have as of now which I am attempting to use via Hive's regexp_extract is --> `test=(.*?)]|.*`

```
select regexp_extract('test=1233]','test=(.*?)]|.*',1);
--1233 (CORRECT)

select regexp_extract('test=1233]323]','test=(.*?)]|.*',1);
--1233 (CORRECT)

select regexp_extract('test=1233323abc','test=(.*?)]|.*',1);
--NULL (Should return 1233323abc)
```

Would appreciate your suggestions. I am halfway there at this point :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew .. why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: I am looking to use regexp_extract as it would have to be a singular function for what we are attempting to build. I tried running the regexp_replace commands you have provided @WiktorStribiżew but it did not work out unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp_extract(col,'test=([^\\]]+)',1);
```

It seems it is more appropriate to use `regexp_replace` here as you want to get the whole input upon no match.

You may use

```
regexp_replace(col, ".*?test=([0-9a-zA-Z]+).*", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJxm9q/1).

The regex will match a whole string and it will remove all text but 1 or more letters and digits after `test=` substring or the whole input will be returned.

If there can be any chars but `]`, use

```
regexp_replace(col, ".*?test=([^\\]]+).*", "$1")
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJxm9q/2).

Comment: thank you! i used the following via hive and it worked :- select regexp_extract('test=123test','.*?test=([^\\]]+).*',1); for those using regexp_replace in hive replace the 1 with $1

Comment: regexp_extract(col,'test=([^\\]]+)',1); works with a single ] character but what if it is one or more characters like ]: for example test=123]: should return 123 but test=123] should return 123] and test=123]:test should return 123. Any idea? Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: @user9429934 Use `.*test=(.*?)(?:]:|\s|$).*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNsSkj/1)) / `test=(.*?)(?:]:|\s|$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNsSkj/2)).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.. greatly appreciate it @Wiktor!